# is there any widget table with resizable column & row size (like in excel) in flutter? if yes, how can i do it?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, widget, flutter-web

[image]

how to create resizable width & height in table widget in flutter like shown in image.
by drawing column & row Edge.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOfjb.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

Columns Resizing in Flutter DataGrid (SfDataGrid)
The SfDataGrid provides support to resize the columns by dragging the right end of the column header. The column resizing can be enabled by setting the SfDataGrid.allowColumnsResizing property to true.

For detail visit
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/columns-resizing